# How to add branch label next to projectile string with smart-mode-line

Tags: mode-line, projectile, vc-mode

This is something I asked on the [official repository](https://github.com/Malabarba/smart-mode-line/issues/129).

By default, `smart-mode-line` displays the current projectile project-name before the buffer-name, and the `vc-mode` string after it:

```
... [P/myproject]BUFFER-NAME :master ...
```

I would like to combine the project name and the branch together, and
display them both before the buffer-name.
Here is what I want to achieve:

```
... [myproject:master]BUFFER-NAME ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No other way (that I know of) than writing a custom mode-line customizing `mode-line-format`.

[Here is how I did it](https://bitbucket.org/angrybacon/dotemacs/src/7f41cb37b6ce314450afcaf59b855a16e6d51181/lisp/init-mode-line.el?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default#init-mode-line.el-95).

And to strip the backend string ("Git" from "Git:master"):

```el
(defadvice vc-mode-line (after me/vc-mode-line () activate)
  "Strip backend from the VC information."
  (when (stringp vc-mode)
    (let ((vc-text (replace-regexp-in-string "^ Git." ":" vc-mode)))
      (setq vc-mode vc-text))))
```